# Postgresql Permission denied for Copy from on Windows

Tags: postgresql

I am running postgresql with pgAdmin4 on windows x64. I just created a database, then a table and now I want to add data to the table from an excel sheet using

`copy table from 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\copy.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;`

I get this error message:

> ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\username\Desktop\copy.csv" for
> reading: Permission denied HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL
> server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility
> such as psql's \copy. SQL state: 42501

I tried running it as admin but it didn't help.
Side note: pgadmin 4 opens on my Firefox browser with high privacy settings in case it has anything to do with it.

Comment: As the hint says, the command you are running is happening _on the Posgres server_, not in the pgAdmin 4 client process. How you run pgAdmin 4 will make no difference.

Comment: You'll need to give whichever user you're logging into the server as permission to read from the directory you're trying to copy from. The permissions need to be set on the server itself. `psql`'s `\copy` command is more lenient with permissions... you could try using that from the server side.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. How can I set the permissions on the server itself?

Answer (score 1):

For people who are still having this issue, one of the fastest workarounds I found (that sidesteps permission changes) is to use the "Users\Public" folder when reading or writing files.

E.g if you want to read in "copy.csv", moving the file's location to "Users\Public\copy.csv" should allow you to read it without explicitly setting permissions for postgres/pgadmin

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are (like me) using postgres both client/server on a local machine. As others have said, the server process needs to be able to access your file.
If you have a look for the postgres.exe process(es) running using task manager, under the 'details' tab, it will show the windows user name that the process is running under.
On my system, that was NETWORK SERVICE.
You can then use the security tab on windows properties for the file or folder you want to access to give access to the user account you found above.
There may be security implications to giving access to that user. I'd suggest limiting those permissions, and do so at your own risk.